# How to isolate content until the first double newline sequence?

Tags: php, regex, substring, preg-replace, preg-match

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I get any content until the first blank line?

**NOTE:** First and second part of the content doesn't always start with ul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match('/\A.*?(?=\s*^\s*$)/smx', $subject, $regs);
$result = $regs[0];
```

Explanation

```
preg_match(
    '/\A    # Start of string
    .*?     # Match any number of characters (as few as possible)
    (?=     # until it is possible to match...
     \s*    #  trailing whitespace, including a linebreak 
     ^      #  Start of line
     \s*    #  optional whitespace
     $      #  End of line
    )       # (End of lookahead assertion)/smx', 
    $subject, $regs);
$result = $regs[0];
```

assuming that you count lines that contain nothing but whitespace as blank lines. If not, remove the "optional whitespace" line.

Comment: echo $result.'<div>...'; puts the <div> on a new line. Any way to have it right after </ul>?

Comment: @user557108: Yes, I've added a line that excludes trailing whitespace from the match.

Answer (score 0):

In a sample string that looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Bum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bum</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Barf</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Barf</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Barf</a></li>
</ul>
```

Tim's `preg_match()` pattern that uses a lazy quantifier and a lookahead will take 432 step to complete.  It also relies on the fact that double newline sequence actually exists in the string (it will fail to match if the double newline doesn't exist).

I think I will recommend a different technique. Use `preg_replace()` on your string with a much simpler (greedy) pattern.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GlnkN))

```
preg_replace('/\R{2}.*/s', '', $html)
```

Not only does it return the desired output regardless of if the double newline sequence occurs in the string, the pattern takes just **7** steps.  This is what I would use in my project.

`\R` matches newline sequences on differnt operating systems.
`s` the s pattern modifier tells the regex engine to inclue newline characters when matching with the wildcard character `.` .